# How to display sentiment and polarity in table. I used Flask to create the code

Tags: python, html, flask

My project is to create sentiment analysis. The first step is to get the data from the database (already done). Then, do the sentiment and display in the form of table in HTML. The data for Question(table header) is displayed successfully. Instead, for Sentiment and Polarity header are not (Figure A). Please help me as I am the new learner.

Figure A:
[image]

The code for app.py:

```
@app.route('/programs/<string:id>/')
def programs(id):
# Create cursor
cur = mysql.connection.cursor()

# Get articles
result = cur.execute("SELECT id,a FROM table WHERE id = %s", [id])

data = cur.fetchall()



for j in data:

    sid_obj = SentimentIntensityAnalyzer() 

    sentiment_dict = sid_obj.polarity_scores(j) 

    if sentiment_dict['compound'] >= 0.05 : 
        sentiment = 'positive'

    elif sentiment_dict['compound'] <= - 0.05 : 
        sentiment = 'negative'

    else : 
        sentiment = 'neutral'



if result > 0:

    return render_template('programs.html', data=data)
else:
    msg = 'No Results Found'
    return render_template('programs.html', msg=msg)




# Close connection
cur.close()
```

Code in html:

```
<h1>Dashboard</h1>
<hr>
<table class="table table-striped">
<tr><th>Question</th>
     <th>Sentiment</th>
     <th>Polarity</th>

</tr>

{% for i in data %}
  <tr>
    <td>{{i.a}}</td>
    <td>{{i.sentiment}}</td>
    <td>{{i.sentiment_dict['compound']}}</td>
  </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: first check what you send to template in `data` - ie. `print(data)`. As for me you don't send these values. You would have to add them to `data` or create new array with all needed values.

Comment: don't change question - now my answer doesn't fit to your problem. IF you have new problem then you should create new question on new page. Or at least you should add it at the end of old question without changing old question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for me you don't send these values in `data`.

You have to create list/dict with all needed values.

```
values = list()  # list for all values

for j in data:

    sid_obj = SentimentIntensityAnalyzer() 

    sentiment_dict = sid_obj.polarity_scores(j) 

    if sentiment_dict['compound'] >= 0.05 : 
        sentiment = 'positive'

    elif sentiment_dict['compound'] <= - 0.05 : 
        sentiment = 'negative'

    else : 
        sentiment = 'neutral'

    # add values to list
    values.append({"a": j, "sentiment": sentiment, "sentiment_dict": sentiment_dict)
```

and send them to template

```
return render_template('programs.html', data=values)
```

Comment: Hi..I have tried your code and it's working..Thank you..But, the problem is with the table in Question header. It is also display programid and q9 (In the picture above. Do you have a recommendation on how to delete it. I just want to display sentence only..Thank you